# How to use -exec option in find command

Tags: command-line, bash, compiz, compiling, scripts

I wanna solve some problems in `compiz` with my *brain* and *hands*.

By the way I entered following command to build `compiz` from source in Ubuntu 12.04

```
find /opt/compiz-built/share/gconf/schemas -exec gconftool-2 --install-schema-file={};
```

I referred that command at http://www.brazzi64.net/blog/building-compiz-from-source-in-ubuntu-12-04/

And following message is shown.

How to use `-exec` option in find command, I guess that it's my mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there. You need a `\;` on the end to let find know where the end of the command is.

```
find /opt/compiz-built/share/gconf/schemas -exec gconftool-2 --install-schema-file={} \;
```

For commands that can take multiple arguments at a time (eg if you wanted to just `stat` each filename) you can use `\+` instead. This will build a compound argument which can execute a faster because it doesn't fork out for every single file:

```
find . -exec stat {} \+
```

That won't work here for your example though.

---

Just a test harness to highlight that quotes aren't required:

```
$ mkdir 1 2 1\ 2               # makes three directories
$ touch {1,2}/single           # puts a file in each of the two singles
$ touch 1\ 2/COMBO             # puts a file in the dir with a space
$ find -type d -exec ls {} \;
1  1 2  2
single
single
COMBO
```

If it wasn't handling quoting for us, we'd see this instead of COMBO:

```
1:
correct

2:
correct
```

Comment: +1. No need for quotes, `find` deals with spaces (and other weirdness) internally.

Comment: Even on arguments for things? Edit: Just tested it and yeah, it does seem to work without quotes. That's pretty fancy.

Comment: I know right? I used to quote the darn thing all the time until someone pointed it out to me.

Comment: Also, `-execdir` is preferred over `-exec` for security reasons (see `man find`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command.

```
find /opt/compiz-built/share/gconf/schemas -exec gconftool-2 --install-schema-file '{}' ';'
```

According to the find command manual($man find). there are actions can predefined in find command such as delete, ls.

In addition to the predefined actions, we can also invoke arbitrary commands.  The 
traditional way of doing this is with the **-exec** action.  This action works like this:

```
-exec command {} ;
```

where command is the name of a command, {} is a symbolic representation of the current 
pathname and the semicolon is a required delimiter indicating the end of the command.

**Again, since the brace and semicolon characters have special meaning to the shell, they 
must be quoted or escaped**.